# Pandas read log file of <key>=<value>

Tags: python, pandas

For some strange reason I'm have to read a log file in the following form:

```
Tue Apr  3 08:51:05 2018 foo=123 bar=321 spam=eggs msg="String with spaces in it"
Tue Apr  3 10:31:46 2018 foo=111 bar=222 spam=eggs msg="Different string with spaces"
...
```

I would like to read it in as the following DataFrame:

```
   bar  foo                       msg  spam                      time
0  321  123  String with spaces in it  eggs  Tue Apr  3 08:51:05 2018
1  222  111          Different string  eggs  Tue Apr  3 10:31:46 2018
...
```

Where each of the each `<key>=<value>` is given it's own column & then the date at the beginning is given it's own column named `time`.

**Is there a `pandas` way of handling this?  (Or only `<key>=<value>` part?)**

Or, at least, is there a better way than regex to split this all up into a form `pandas` can accept?

Comment: Did you try extracting all of your key/value pairs in a `dict`? Note that the value needs to be of type `list` (or sequence). Then you'd only have to do `df = pd.DataFrame(data=my_dict)`

Comment: @edouardtheron is there an easy way to convert from key/value to dictionary without regex?  (I'll google).  Also, `key=value` is what I was looking for, not sure why my brain went to `property=value`

Comment: Considering you are parsing a string which represents a single line from your log file:

```pairs = line.split(' ')
my_dict = {}
for pair in pairs:
    key = pair.split('=')[0]
    value = pair.split('=')[1]
    my_dict[key] = value
```
Does that work?

Comment: Sorry, the formatting in comments sucks... But you get the idea. EDIT: Moreover, it won't work because you specified that your strings have spaces in them. Nevermind

Comment: @edouardtheron That was my first thought, but the `key=values` can have spaces and/or `=`s in the values.  So the `line.split(' ')` wouldn't quite work.

Comment: @edouardtheron Okay, so I came up with an solution that's pretty much what you suggested, but using the `shlex` library to split the line up.  I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a nudge in the right direction from @edouardtheron & the module `shlex`.

**If you have a better solution please feel free to answer**

But, here's what I came up with, first, import libraries:

```
import shlex
import pandas as pd
```

Create some example data:

```
# Example data
test_string = """
Tue Apr  3 08:51:05 2018 foo=123 bar=321 spam=eggs msg="String with spaces in it"
Tue Apr  3 10:31:46 2018 foo=111 bar=222 spam=eggs msg="Different string"
"""
```

Create regex that matches the entire line but groups it into

1: Date at the beginning `((?:[a-zA-Z]{3,4} ){2} \d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \d{4})`

2: everything else `(.*)`

```
patt = re.compile('((?:[a-zA-Z]{3,4} ){2} \d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \d{4}) (.*)')
```

Loop through lines in test string and apply regex, then parse the `key_values` into a dictionary using `shlex`

```
sers = []
for line in test_string.split('\n'):

    matt = re.match(patt, line)
    if not matt:
        # skip the empty lines
        continue
    # Extract Groups
    time, key_values = matt.groups()

    ser = pd.Series(dict(token.split('=', 1) for token in shlex.split(key_values)))
    ser['log_time'] = time
    sers.append(ser)
```

Finally concatenate all the lines into a single DataFrame:

```
# Concat serieses into a dataframe
df = pd.concat(sers, axis=1).T
# Change the type of 'log_time' to an actual date
df['log_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['log_time'], format='%a %b  %d %X %Y', exact=True)
```

This produces the following DataFrame:

```
   bar  foo                       msg  spam            log_time
0  321  123  String with spaces in it  eggs 2018-04-03 08:51:05
1  222  111          Different string  eggs 2018-04-03 10:31:46
```